# How to tell VLC 2.3.0 to scan a local folder on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, video, vlc

I'm trying to load some of my son's favourites videos on his iPad (7.0.4).
When I plug the iPad on my Linux Box (mint 17), the iPad folders are automatically mounted in read and write mode. So no problem to transfer the files on the iPad.

Strangely enough though I can't get VLC to detect the files. It's a breeze on android's version of VLC but the IOS version of VLC has a different UI.

All sorts of ways are available (itune, wifi upload, dropbox and gdrive) but no way to scan a folder apparently.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS does not expose its filesystem to apps, outside their own sandbox. As far as an app is concerned, the only files on the iPad (or iPhone, or iPod Touch) are its own files, in its own sandbox.

You can upload the files to VLC by either using 'open with' (from Dropbox or from other apps that expose the ability to open files in other apps), or by going to iTunes and copying the videos to the VLC app. This puts the files in VLC's own sandbox.

Comment: Thanks, I used the wifi upload to work out where the files were stored and then discovered the sqlite db where the files are described. I believe I could achieve my goal by dropping files in the sandbox and registering them in the sqlite db.  All other means involve the network and are several order of magnitude slower than a mere USB copy.  One more item in the 'cons' column for the ipad I'm afraid.